# pagePath and nextPagePath in analytics api not working

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I try to get a list of pages people go after visiting the selected page. `pagePath` is a starting page, `nextPagePath` is the result list of pages I'm interested in. I included a filter to show only one starting page. But the result I get is confusing:

[image: google query explorer page path]

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

Use ga:previousPagePath instead of ga:pagePath. For the reason to me unknown, ga:pagePath and ga:nexPagePath refers in GA API to the same thing.